# Individual Repeating 'Hashem Elokeikhem Emes'

Tags: tefilla, shema

When reading Keriat Shema without a minyan, to complete 248 words, the Minhat Ela'zar says that the individual should repeat 'Hashem Elokeikhem Emes'. Is there any drawback to this position? (It's new to me, but seems direct and reasonable, so I'm wondering why it doesn't seem to have caught on.)

Comment: This is the position of the Mechaber, as found in the Shulchan Aruch. I know for a fact that Chabad holds this way.

Comment: This is also the position of the Shulchan Aruch Harav iirc.

Comment: @paquda https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81352/el-melech-neeman-not-in-chabad-siddurim/81356#81356

Answer (score 2):

Some possibilities that come to mind:

1. *hefsek* (unnecessary interruption between the *Shema* and its blessings)
2. *motzi shem shamayim l'vatala* (saying the divine name without justification)
3. going against an established *minhag klal yisrael* (custom)
4. going against an established *p'sak halacha* (assuming the normative ruling is not to)

Comment: Re: hefsek, the popular custom of saying 'keil melekh ne'eman' seems to be a hefseik too.

Comment: Re: motzi shem shamayim l'vatala, saying 'keil melekh ne'eman' also includes Hashems name.

Comment: Indeed. And I believe that is why many refrain from doing so. You asked if there were any drawbacks. This is a potential one. I am sure there are many who hold that one/the other/neither would be an actual hefsek, akin to Hashkiveinu...