# "El melech ne'eman" not in Chabad siddurim

Tags: chabad, shema, nusach-ari

There is a common custom amongst many to recite the words

> אל מלך נאמן

before Kriyas Shema when there is no minyan. However, in all Chabad siddurim I have davened from, this phrase is not there. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe it's not as common as you thought...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The First Chabad Rebbe, known as the Alter Rebbe (and also known as "The Rav (Ba'al HaTanya)", the author of Shulchan Aruch Harav) writes in his [Siddur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=651):

> יחיד המתפלל לעצמו יחזור תיבות אני ה' אלהיכם
>
> An individual praying alone should repeat the words *Ani Hashem Eloheichem*

This is to exclude *minhag ashkenaz* (and what he writes in his Shulchan Aruch) that an individual says "אל מלך נאמן".

Comment: Could you please translate?

Comment: Thanks so much. That's fascinating. Do we know for sure "keyl melech neemon" is excluded on this account?

Comment: Also, if one is saying less than the whole Shema - for example, just "Shema Yisroel" - should one then say the Keyl Melech neemon, because one will not be repeating "Ani - E-lokeichem"?

Comment: @SAH "Do we know for sure "keyl melech neemon" is excluded on this account?" It's not printed in the *Siddur*, and the quote I brought is from where "keyl melech neemon" would have been mentioned.

Comment: @SAH If one is not saying the whole *Shema*, there's little reason to say anything extra (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91357/9643) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87110/9643) - unfortunately there are no answers yet for those questions).